# Posts are not being indexed

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

So I have a fairly new blog up and running, and while I'm aware of sandboxing, one post immediately started to receive impressions and got some queries.

```
post-sitemap.xml - Sitemap processed successfully
11 discovered pages
```

All pages are discovered, but only this one was indexed. This is from URL inspection for that one post:

```
check_circle
Page indexing Page is indexed Discovery Sitemaps https://website.com/sitemap_index.xml Referring page None detected Crawl Last crawl Sep 17, 2023 Crawled as Googlebot smartphone Crawl allowed? Yes Page fetch Successful Indexing allowed? Yes Indexing User-declared canonical https://website.com/slug/ Google-selected canonical  Inspected URL
```

Through URL inspection, I also manually requested indexing for a few more, and they also got indexed, but some just don't. Here are two examples of posts that are not indexed, different reasons:

```
Page indexing
Page is not indexed: Crawled - currently not indexed Discovery Sitemaps https://website.com/sitemap_index.xml Referring page https://website.com/ Crawl Last crawl Sep 19, 2023 Crawled as Googlebot desktop Crawl allowed? Yes Page fetch Successful Indexing allowed? N/A Indexing User-declared canonical N/A Google-selected canonical  N/A

Page indexing Page is not indexed: Redirect error Discovery Sitemaps No referring sitemaps detected Referring page None detected URL might be known from other sources that are currently not reported Crawl Last crawl Sep 19, 2023 Crawled as Googlebot desktop Crawl allowed? Yes Page fetch info Failed: Redirect error Indexing allowed? N/A Indexing User-declared canonical N/A Google-selected canonical  N/A
```

Why some got indexed, and the others are not? And how to interpret this info above - what needs to be done here? Crawled - currently not indexed? Redirect error? No referring sitemaps?
Should this all sort out by itself as the site ages, or I need to request manually each time? I'm confused... or this is just how Google rolls :)